# How to pass data from a login service to main views in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

My app's login view accesses an external service to validate the user's credentials and return a swift object.
The login view calls a login function here:

```
func login(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        showProgressView = true
        //checks with APIService
        APIService.shared.login(credentials: credentials) { [unowned self](result:Result<Bool, Authentication.AuthenticationError>) in showProgressView = false 
            switch result {
            case .success:
                completion(true)
            case .failure(let authError):
                credentials = Credentials()
                error = authError
                completion(false)
            }
        }
    }
```

The API service then does this:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, HTTPURLResponse, Error in
                typealias YourDecodedObject = [StudentClass]
                if let data = data {
                    do {
                        let decodedObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(YourDecodedObject.self, from: data)
                        completion(.success(true))
                    } catch {
                        print("could not decode ❌")
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                        completion(.failure(.invalidCredentials))
                    }
                }
            }.resume()
```

How would I send "YourDecodedObject" back to my login view?

Comment: You should send decoded object via the completion handlers. Another way is to initialise a shared StudendClass object In API that you can use in login view.

Comment: Is it SwiftUI or UIKit app ?

Comment: @PtitXav it is a SwiftUI app. How would I send the object through the completion handlers or through a shared object?

Comment: check answer given by scrap_tech_guy

Answer (score 0):

**SwiftUI answer**

I recommend having all of the backend stuff in one class that conforms to `ObservableObject`.

```swift
class ContentModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text:String = "Hello, World!"
}
```

In this case, I named the class `ContentModel` and declared it in a file with **the same name**. Then you can access the data in whatever view by:

```swift
struct LoginView: View {
    // Access data in your class
    
    @EnvironmentObject var model: ContentModel

    var body: some View {
        Text(model.text)
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add `.environmentObject(ContentModel())` to the view you're using the data in.

```swift
@main
struct StuduWidgetsApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            LoginView()
                .environmentObject(ContentModel())
        }
    }
}
```

**PS**: If you want to use Preview Provider, you're gonna have to add there `.environmentObject(ContentModel())` too.

```swift
struct LoginView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LoginView()
            .environmentObject(ContentModel())
    }
}
```

If you want to share data from ContentModel across multiple targets open the file with ContentModel class, access the "Inspectors Menu" (on the right in Xcode) and go to the "File Inspector" tab. Locate "Target Membership"

[image]

and tick all the targets you want your data to be used in, then apply the same approach as above.

Hope this helps! It's a complicated approach, but it's worth it.

Comment: The post was not tagged SwiftUI.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, specified that on the top of my answer.

Comment: I combined my APIService function into my LoginViewModel class. How would I go and make my decodedObject variable @Published. Right now, when I try to publish that value, it gives me a lot of errors.

Comment: I don't think @Published wrapper is necessary in your case. Try running it without it and let me know!

Comment: I separated my APIService and LoginViewModel classes again because I ran into many errors. Is there a way for me to simply access the decodedObject in the closure of my call to the APIService from the LoginViewModel? Also, right now I am using the LoginViewModel class as a StateObject private var, and nothing works when I change it to an EnvironmentObject like the one in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you wanted to pass `decodedObject` or `AuthenticationError` objects back to `func login` based on success or failure.

If it is so then you need to modify your `completion` handler as below:

```
    APIService.shared.login(credentials: credentials) { [unowned self](result:Result<Data?, Authentication.AuthenticationError?>) in
```

here, you can pass success object i.e. `decodedObject` in `Data` and `AuthenticationError` in error part.

You don't need to have `Bool` here to identify `success` or `failure`. You can just check either one for nil or data present and call `completion` handler as follows:

```
if let data = data {
       do {
             let decodedObject = try                   
             JSONDecoder().decode(YourDecodedObject.self, from: data)
             completion(.success(decodedObject, nil))
          } catch {
              print("could not decode ❌")
              print(error.localizedDescription)                   
              completion(.failure(nil, .invalidCredentials))
          }
 }
```

I made both callback response parameters as `nil` so it won't be problem in any scenario.

Comment: This gives me a lot of errors. First, decodedObject can't conform to Data. Second, AuthenticationError doesn't conform to Error. Third, the completion has too many parameters.